# AWS unable to see RDS mysql DB after connecting via mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Stupid question maybe but for some reasons, i am unable to see my RDS mysql db instance after connecting via mysql from my ec2 instance. The EC2 and the RDS security groups have the 3306 port open between them, no issues. The database is already created as i can see it on the RDS console.

```
mysql -h RDS endpoint -P 3306 -u root -p

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| innodb             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Regards,

Ochen

Comment: What was your db name?

Comment: Maybe your endpoint is incorrect.

Comment: RDS endpoint is correct. Strange that i just don't see the database that i created earlier...

Comment: as  you can see from my earlier output, i can connect to the RDS fine....

Comment: That is what I am asking when you created the database what was its name and how did you create it?

Comment: create database dbname;

Comment: it was there right after  i created it. Now i don't see it...

Comment: Ok so you don't remember it. Ok please create the database now from this mysql console that is the only thing to do now.

Comment: it's not about i don't remember. I should see my created database if i do a show databases; Re-creating the database again is not  the issue. Whats beats me is how   did it disappear?

Comment: Ok but then you the best way is to create support ticket to aws. They can check the logs what happened and help you out.

Comment: Maybe obvious question, but are you sure that you are the only one who could had accessed the DB?

Comment: yes dead sure. I'll create another new db then